# Stop jQuery Mobile Horizontal Radio Buttons from Breaking or Wrapping

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm attempting to create two horizontal radio button groups side by side using html from the jQuery Mobile demo page.
The problem is that the radio buttons break and start to wrap to the next line when there is still plenty of space between them.  Is there a way I can set them not to wrap until there is virtually no space between the two on small screens?

You can see the what's happening in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bunoxL4r/1/)

Also, I would like to align the second radio grouping to the right, but adding `text-align:right` or `position:relative; right:0px` to #SecondGroup didn't have any effect.

Here's my code:

```
             <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset  class="ui-grid-a ">

                        <div class="ui-block-a" id="FirstGroup">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" data-type="horizontal" >
                                <input type="radio" name="same" id="sold" value="on" checked="checked">
                                <label for="sold">One</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="same" id="active" value="off">
                                <label for="active">Two</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>                      

                        <div class="ui-block-b" id="SecondGroup">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" data-type="horizontal" >
                                <input type="radio" name="conditionSame" id="all" value="on" checked="checked">
                                <label for="all">One</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="conditionSame" id="used" value="on" >
                                <label for="used">Two</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="conditionSame" id="new" value="on">
                                <label for="new">Three</label>
                            </fieldset>

                        </div>                          

                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had invisible white-spaces `&nbsp;` in your code (see the screenshot below). After removing them the wrapping works.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bunoxL4r/3/

In this screenshot of your fiddle's source you can see these `&nbsp;`:
[image: Screenshot of your fiddle's source]

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much!  Do you know how the white-spaces got there?

Comment: :-) copy and paste, eventually?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - looking at the source, I found similar sets of non-break spaces;
There were none in my code so how did they get there?
I had indented the code using tabs (use spaces now!). Somehow, the tabs got converted to non-break spaces. Taking out all the indents solved the problem.